# DataLoader Command Line - Error

Tags: data-loader

While executing the steps mentioned in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dataLoader.meta/dataLoader/command_line_intro.htm.

I am facing the error while at the step 5. I am not sure why the secuirty token error is coming

Error :

> 2018-05-21 19:11:50,332 ERROR [accountInsert] client.PartnerClient runOperation (PartnerClient.java:332) - Error while calling web service operation: login, error was:
>   [LoginFault [ApiFault  exceptionCode='LOGIN_MUST_USE_SECURITY_TOKEN'
>    exceptionMessage='Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out. Are you at a new location? When accessing Salesforce--either via a desktop client or the API--from outside of your companyÆs trusted networks, you must add a security token to your password to log in. To get your new security token, log in to Salesforce. From your personal settings, enter Reset My Security Token in the Quick Find box, then select Reset My Security Token.'
>    extendedErrorDetails='{[0]}'
>   ]
>   ]

Comment: Did you append your security token to your login password?

Comment: Or in Profile settings add login IP ranges as 0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255

Answer (score 0):

In "Step Two: Create the Encrypted Password" you will need to get add the security token from your target sandbox to the password like below.

encrypt.bat –e  "\key.txt"

The following link provides information on how to obtain a security token for your target org:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=user_security_token.htm&type=5